# Youtube video API using playerVars: { 'rel': 0 } for removing but it not working

Tags: api, video, youtube

I try to remove suggested video from my Youtube player, I am using the code which are given below but still no luck.
I have try to find solution by searching this site but can't able to find any solution. Please help me.

```
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: { 
             'autoplay':       1,
             'controls':       1, 
             'rel':            0,
             'showinfo':       0,
             'modestbranding': 1,
             'autohide':       1,
             'enablejsapi':    1,
             'html5':          1
      },
      videoId: '<?php echo youtube_id_from_url(get_post_meta(get_the_id(),"mvyt_url",true)); ?>',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

I have try to remove related video from the video , but it does not work for me .
I try , 'rel':0, rel:'0', 'rel':'0' , but no luck. also try html5 : 1

Please help me!

Comment: I badly need this solution . Please help me ..

Answer (score -1):

I found by placing rel=0 both in the src of the iframe as well as in the playerVars it worked, e.g.

```
<iframe id="hero_video_player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qREKP9oijWI?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://this.deakin.edu.au&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and:

```
var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('hero_video_player', {
            playerVars: {
                'rel': 0
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
      }
```

Hope that helps.